Shell script can't be executed by LaunchDeamon or LaunchAgent
macOS 14.2.1 (23C71)
I have this shell script which copies a folder to an external hard drive using rsync:
#!/bin/bash

SOURCE_DIR="/Users/tristan/Library/Application Support/Postgres/var-16"
BACKUP_DIR="/Volumes/Malbec/Backup"

BACKUP_NAME="backup_$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S)"
BACKUP_PATH="$BACKUP_DIR/$BACKUP_NAME"

rsync -a --delete "$SOURCE_DIR/" "$BACKUP_PATH/"

Running this script manually works fine but when trying to execute it with a LaunchDeamon/LaunchAgent it doesn't work. Also when the backup folder is on the internal hard drive it works without a problem.
This is the plist:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>postgres.backup</string>
    <key>UserName</key>
    <string>tristan</string>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/Users/tristan/Server_Backup/daily.0000_out.log</string>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/Users/tristan/Server_Backup/daily.0000_error.log</string>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/Users/tristan/Server_Backup/Backup.sh</string>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Hour</key>
        <integer>18</integer>
        <key>Minute</key>
        <integer>5</integer>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>

And this is the error I get:
rsync: mkdir "/Volumes/Malbec/Backup/backup_20240503_180246" failed: Operation not permitted (1)
rsync error: error in file IO (code 11) at /AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/0032d1ee-80fd-11ee-8227-6aecfccc70fe/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync/main.c(545) [receiver=2.6.9]
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (8 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at /AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/0032d1ee-80fd-11ee-8227-6aecfccc70fe/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync/io.c(453) [sender=2.6.9]
rsync: mkdir "/Volumes/Malbec/Backup/backup_20240503_180505" failed: Operation not permitted (1)
rsync error: error in file IO (code 11) at /AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/0032d1ee-80fd-11ee-8227-6aecfccc70fe/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync/main.c(545) [receiver=2.6.9]
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (8 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at /AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/0032d1ee-80fd-11ee-8227-6aecfccc70fe/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync/io.c(453) [sender=2.6.9]

I'm guessing it's some kind of permission problem. I have already added rsync to full disk access in the Privacy & Security settings.
Edit:
I let the thing sit for a few days and when I came back it ran and made backups. It just started working out of nowhere when I was away.

Please open the Info dialog on the destination volume. If the checkbox to ignore ownership on the volume is checked, uncheck it and test.

Another solution is LaunchControl.  I don't generally favor third-party commercial apps, but it is quite good IMHO.

I did try launch control but I didn't quite like it.

The box of ignoring the ownership was checked and I did uncheck it but the error doesn't go away.

Does this answer your question? LaunchDeamon file doesn't work

That's actually my post xD. I just started a new discussion solely for the execution of the shell script.
